# Incorrect PHP SOAP Formatting

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I am trying to make use of the stand soapClient for PHP. I can make a class successfully using SOAP UI however when I trry and make that call using PHP this is the difference.

```
 <arrInputs xsi:type="ns1:KeyValueArrayInput" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:KeyValueArray[]"  >
            <item xsi:type="ns1:KeyValueArray">
                <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Realm</Key>
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test</Value>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="ns1:KeyValueArray">
                <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">UserName</Key>
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test15</Value>
            </item>
```

Now when I try send it via the php soap client I get this.

```
<arrInputs SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:KeyValueArray[22]" xsi:type="ns1:KeyValueArrayInput">
            <item xsi:type="ns1:KeyValueArray">
                <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Realm</Key>
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test</Value>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="ns1:KeyValueArray">
                <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">UserName</Key>
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test2</Value>
            </item>
```

Any suggestions as to how the type and the array type have been switched around. If I put the type in front of the arrayType all is good.

```
  $creationFields = array();
    $creationFields['strSessionID'] = $this->getSessionHash();
    $arrInputs = array();

    foreach ($params as $k => $v)
    {         
        $arrInputs[] = array('Key' => $k, 'Value' => $v);
    }

    $creationFields['arrInputs'] = $arrInputs;

    __soapCall('methodName', $creationFields);
```

This is out of the WSDL:

```
<message name="methodName"><part name="strSessionID" type="xsd:string" /><part name="arrInputs" type="tns:KeyValueArrayInput" /></message>
```

Comment: Do you get an error in PHP?

Comment: No error at all it does the call to the third party API but fails due to this incorrect format. They return a response telling me the formatting is incorrect

Comment: Could you post original error response telling that formatting is incorrect?

Comment: Unfortunately it is to a 3rd party and they just return a generic error not the actual soap error